# Matlab Error : Missing domain attribute 'min'

Tags: matlab, symengine

when I use in Matlab:

```
symmin=@(x,y)feval(symengine,'min',x,y);

symmin(3,4)

ans=

3
```

but if I want to find the minimum of a vector:

```
symmin=@(x)feval(symengine,'min',x); % or 

symmin=@(x)feval(symengine,'min',x(1:10));

a=1:10;

symmin(a)

error using mupadengine/feval (line 187)

Missing domain attribute 'min'.
```

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Do you have to use `feval` along with `symengine` or it's just your first attempt to solve it and you tried using that approach?

Comment: I have to replace "min" function in "vpasolve" function because of the error:
"Error using sym/min (line 101)
Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers." The use of feval is the only suggestion I found.Thanks